# Read XML on Hololens (UWP)

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I'm working on a project for Microsoft Hololens (UWP) in Unity3D where I'm reading from an XML file. It works in Unity but as I port it to Hololens, it won't work. I guess I have to read the file in another way but I can't figure out how.

As of now, the app is crashing on Hololens when I try to debug so I can't get any log errors (I can launch it from its menu though).

I'm reading the XML like:

```
XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLFile));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/" + path);
XMLFile images = (XMLFile)seri.Deserialize(reader);
return images;
```

Then I have the XML parts in classes like

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Image {

    public int ID;
    public string Filename;
   ...
```

How can I access the XML file in UWP?

Comment: I wonder if the Unity application directories aren't...correct for the hololens (yet). Can you try [doing it the Microsoft way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files#reading-from-a-file)?

Comment: If your device is plugged to the computer when running from VS sln, you can see the debug in the output window. It will also print whether you have a null reference (most likely). Else you can use the portal which will store the logs of your session.